# What does it mean for two equations to be 'invariant'?

Tags: calculus, statistics, data-analysis, stationary-processes, multivariate-polynomial

I have watched a few videos yet I am still having a bit of trouble. I have included the two equations here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It says that the two equations are invariant and must be anchored. I am totally lost on what the person means by that

Comment: Hint: make the transformation $z_{i_h}\mapsto z_{i_h}+c$ for all $z_{i_h}$. What do you observe? What could then invariant mean?

Comment: Please try to type out the relevant parts using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); avoid images.

Comment: @neitherNor I have dyscalculia so i am really really bad at math. This year i am taking math related subjects but i am still very slow. I tried to think it out but i have no idea at all. Please can you explain me in an easy manner?

Comment: OK: if you make the trafo $z_{i_h}\mapsto z_{i_h}+c$, which also goes by the name "translation", you will find out that $P_{i_g}$ doesn't change, which goes by the name "invariant". Being invariant with respect to translation thus just means that $P_{i_g}$ does not change when you add the same constant to all $z_{i_h}$.

Comment: Now, this poses some problem because you end up with many solutions (different possible combinations of $z_{i_h}$ which result in the same $P_{i_g}$) and you normally want a single, unique one. Thus we have to come up with some extra criterion which makes one of the solutions more special than the others. This is called "anchored" here. The reason for this naming is that we figuratively throw an anchor at $\sum z_{i_h}=0$. This anchor allows is to compare and rank solutions (by the sum of the $z_{i_h}$, i.e. the distance to the anchor) and to pick the best one (the one with $\sum z_{i_h}=0$).